# Проблема с асинхронностью функции в JS

Tags: javascript, async-await

столкнулся с асинхронностью. Функция filebartocanvas выполняется очень медленно. Как дождаться её выполнения и только потом продолжить цикл? В дубликате ответ найти не смог.

```
function download() {
  for(let i=0;i<countFile;i++){

    filebartocanvas(fileArray[i][0]); // - медленная функция 

    console.log('Этот вывод быстрее чем функция выше'); // выполняется раньше, чем функция выше   
  }
}

function filebartocanvas(name){
  for(let i=0;i<countFile;i++){
    if(name == fileArray[i][0]){
      nowFile = i;
      cx = fileArray[i][1];
      ourfile = fileArray[i][2];
      var commands = fileArray[i][3];
      break;
    }
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
    loadImageURL(cx, reader.result, commands);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(ourfile);
  infobar.textContent = 'File: ' + name;
}
```

Comment: «В дубликате ответ найти не смог» — значит плохо искали

Comment: можете дать подсказку, что конкретно в дубликате мне может помочь?

Comment: В самом заплюсованном ответе всё есть, просто берите любой понравившийся способ и применяйте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554291